# how to post multiple photos in instagram programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a demo to share multiple photos on different social platforms. I was able to post a single picture using the code on Instagram but i am not sure how to post multiple images on it. I am not sure even if Instagram provides such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
ArrayList<Uri> images = new ArrayList<Uri>();
Files[] imagesFiles; //your imagesFile

for(String path : imagesFiles) {
File file = new File(path);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
files.add(uri);
}

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, images);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
intent.setType("image/jpeg"); /* This example is sharing jpeg images. */
intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for(String path : filesToSend /* List of the files you want to send */) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    files.add(uri);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
startActivity(intent);
```

This could definitely be simplified but I left some lines in so you can break down each step that is needed.

**NOTE**: Starting in API 24, sharing file URIs will cause a FileUriExposedException. You can either switch your compileSdkVersion to 23 or lower or you can use [content URIs with a FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html).

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE typ=image/jpeg flg=0x1 pkg=com.instagram.android clip={image/jpeg U:content://whatsappsharedemo.com.whatysappsharedemo.provider/external_files/Download/Image1.jpg ...} (has extras) }
Not Working

Comment: what is your package name at intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android"); ?

Comment: is instagram installed in that device?

Comment: yes instagram is installed. and package name was set as mentioned. i am able to share single image. i am trying to have a work around for multiple

Comment: were you able to find any solution to this? I am also looking for a way to share multiple images from my app to instagram.

Comment: Have anyone found the solution? Is this possible now?